# NetConnection to AMFPHP failed on iOS

Tags: ios, amfphp

I've a problem with my Adobe Air mobile application.
I'm using NetConnection class to connect my app to AMFPHP on a server to load my database information.
When I launch the app with an Android device, all works fine.
But, when I'm trying to launch the app on iOS device I got an error :

```
code : "NetConnection.Call.Failed"
description : "HTTP: Failed"
details : "http://serveuripadress/amfphp/Amfphp"
level : "error"
```

I'm not able to find an issue for that problem.

Did somebody can help me solve this ?
Glassalau

Comment: Could this have something to do with security? What happens if you try another URL, for example stackoverflow.com?